# Cannot clone my array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clone my array of objects. Every one tells to use slice(0) but i don't understand, it's not working, check the fiddle. The property is avalaible in the two arrays.

I want to edit my objects in the first array and not in my second too.
I already checked : [How to clone a Javascript Array of Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523881/how-to-clone-a-javascript-array-of-objects) It's the same with concat, extend. The only one i found is JSON.parse. I want to understand why people say the method slice cloned arrays.

```
var arr = [{'obj1':1}, {'obj2':2}];
var clone = arr.slice(0);
clone[0].test = "defined";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkzv2mp0/2/

Comment: What you want is a *deep* clone, not a *shallow* clone.

Comment: Because `JSON.stringify` serializes everything into text form and `JSON.parse` makes objects out of that. No reference is kept. `slice(0)` is, as the answer already says, a shallow cloning method. I’m not exactly sure, where the misunderstanding is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript Reference this question for deep cloning

Comment: It does clone array check `arr === clone // false`. But it doesn't clone elements `arr[0] === clone[0] //true`

Comment: Ok, just understood, thanks. I will use var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));

Comment: The fiddler is not working because it is not recognizing the jQuery. You can look at the inspector on your browser. I just changed the slice from slice(0) to slice() and it worked for me.

Comment: I forgot Jquery CDN. I added it. But it the same with slice().

Comment: This isn’t answering the question at all and there’s no difference between `slice(0)` and `slice()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiddler is pure JS. does not havejquery included.

See working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zkzv2mp0/3/

But as you can see using `slice(0);` is a Shallow clone, where you want to update one without updating the original (deep clone) `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))`

Answer (score 0):

```
var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

You could use JSON Stringify and JSON Parse to clone an Array. But be careful this only works if your array contains JSON serializable content.

Answer (score 0):

Ain't cristal clear what you want to do...

But here is what I think you try to achieve:

```js
// Your initial array of objects.
var arr = [{'obj1':1}, {'obj2':2}];

// A cloned array of objects.
var clone = jQuery.extend(true, [], arr);

// Now sliced, keep the first object only
clone = clone.slice(0,1);
console.log(clone);

// Change the value of the object.
clone[0].obj1 = "defined";
console.log(clone);

// Show them in page.
$("#testarr").html(arr[0].obj1);
$("#testclone").html(clone[0].obj1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
In arr :
<span id="testarr">
</span></p>
<p>
In clone :
<span id="testclone">
</span>
</p>
```