# ReactJS Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I am using React.

I have an array of objects in my state.

```
this.state = {
  team: [{
    name:'Bob',
    number:23
  },
  {
    name:'Jim',
    number:43
  }]
}
```

When I try to make a copy of the array to change a object's property, I don't get the results I want.

I have tried:

```
let tempTeam = [...this.state.team]
```

Any change to tempTeam also mutates this.state.team

AND

```
let tempTeam = this.state.team.map(player => return {...player})
```

This just throws an error, it doesn't like `{...player}`

How can I get the array of objects without it referencing `this.state.team`?

Comment: What error does it throw? I can see a syntax error as you have `}}` instead of `})` at the end of the line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone a Javascript Array of Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523881/how-to-clone-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error in the posted code. If you change it to:

```
let tempTeam = this.state.team.map(player => ({...player}));
```

Or:

```
let tempTeam = this.state.team.map(player => { 
                 return { ...player };
               });
```

You will get a new array with the same object values without the references.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.assign` and spread syntax create shallow copies. If you mutate a nested property in the copied one you also mutate original object.

Most of the time we use `map`, `filter`, `slice` to get a new array by using the original one. But, even using those methods, we should not mutate the properties directly, we should return again new ones using `Object.assign` or spread syntax again.

As explained you have a syntax error in your code, if you fix it you can get the new array. But, most of the time you will do operations like these:

```js
const state = {
  team: [{
    name:'Bob',
    number:23
  },
  {
    name:'Jim',
    number:43
  }]
};

const changeAll = state.team.map( player => ({
  ...player, number: player.number + 1, 
}));

// or

const playerTheOne = state.team.filter(player => player.number === 23);
const notPlayerTheOne = state.team.filter(player => player.number !== 23);

// or

const changeJustOne = state.team.map( player => {
  if ( player.number === 23 ) {
    return { ...player, name: "Joe" };
  }
  return player;
});
console.log( state.team );
console.log( changeAll );
console.log( playerTheOne );
console.log( notPlayerTheOne );
console.log( changeJustOne );
```

As you can see, you don't create a new array then mutate it, you are mutating it while you are creating it.

Comment: What do you mean by this:
"If you mutate a nested property in the copied one you also mutate original object."
Spreading and mapping like he does then modifying the copy will *not* change the original.

Comment: My first sentence is about `Object.assign` and spread syntax. After mapping (even without using spread or `Object.assign`) of course does not mutate the original one.

Comment: If you map without spreading it *will* mutate the original one... I think you have everything backwards lol

Comment: You are damn right here! Thank you, I've updated my poor knowledge and also my answer :) I did not know that even after mapping it uses the same reference. I always think that it is a totally new array after mapping it.

Comment: Happy to help :D I also needed to make sure I'm not just crazy.

Comment: @CodeDraken, definitely you are not :) I'm the confused one here. I never mutate the arrays or objects without returning new items, this is why I am surprised. But, I should have thought that if we return the item itself it will use the same reference as the original one. It is very clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Using Array.slice() creates a clone, so this should should work:

```
let tempTeam = this.state.team.slice();
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice): "For object references (and not the actual object), `slice` copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object." So there will still be references in this case.