# angular 6 reseting one array object is reseting another as well

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6`.

In my component I have two array variables like

```
processedItems: Array<any> = [];
totalProductItems: Array<any> = [];
```

and processing functions like

```
ngOnInit() {
  $products.forEach(async (e) => {
    const res = await this.scraperService.scrapSingle(e.url).toPromise();
    if (res.status.http_code === 200) {
      const properties = this.scraperService.processSingleProduct(res.contents);

      const p_item = {};
      p_item['properties'] = properties;

      this.totalProductItems.push(p_item);

      this._applyFilter();
    }
  }


private _applyFilter() {
  if (!this.filterData) {
    // if nothing to filter, set totalProductItems;
    this.processedItems = this.totalProductItems;
  } else {
    console.log('applying filter');

    // reset processedItems
    this.processedItems.length = 0;

    // this now prints blank array
    console.log(this.totalProductItems);

  }
}
```

Setting length property of `this.processedItems` to 0 is also emptying the `this.totalProductItems`.

Why so? How can I keep these variables separate and independent?

Comment: Because `this.processedItems = this.totalProductItems;`: bith variables reference the same array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone a Javascript Array of Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523881/how-to-clone-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/value-vs-reference.php):

> if you assign an array to a variable or pass an array to a function, it is the reference to the original array that is copied or passed, not the value of the array.

So, when changing `length` property in your local array you actually modifying also referenced array.

Some solutions: assign to your variable a copy of array, which may be achieved in several ways:

- `this.processedItems = [...this.totalProductItems];`
- `this.processedItems = this.totalProductItems.concat();`
- `this.processedItems = this.totalProductItems.slice(0);`

or instead of modifying `length` property reset a whole local array:

instead of `this.processedItems.length = 0;`, do:

```
this.processedItems = [];
```

Comment: The link you posted is broken.